# My first guard, is it appropriate here?

Tags: swift2, guard-statement

I'm playing with Swift 2 and I'm looking through my code for instances where I'm guarding and I might want to use `guard`. Here's one...

```
var mods : String = ""
let modpath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(filename, ofType: "ini", inDirectory: "mods/gamedata")
if modpath?.length > 0 {
    mods = try! String(contentsOfFile: modpath!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
} else {
    mods = ""
}
```

The goal of this code is to read the contents of a text file into `mods`. This file may or may not exist, so I want to test whether it does before I try to read the contents.

Is this an appropriate place to use `guard`? It appears it only has the `else` syntax, not the `then` side, so you can't directly match this syntax. I could set mods to "" at the start and then guard the read, but it's not clear to me this really improves the readability?

As a side note, I find it very weird that String(contentsOfFile) throws, while bundle.pathForResource() simply returns a nil. I prefer the later.

Answer (score 0):

In this Situation I would suggest to use the ternary operator:

```
let modpath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(filename, ofType: "ini", inDirectory: "mods/gamedata")
let mods = modpath?.length > 0  ? try! String(contentsOfFile: modpath!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) : ""
```

On the other hand you can't even use guard in this case because the else block has to quit the scope with `return`, `break`, `continue` or `throw`

Comment: Right, which is why I asked. It seems that guard, theoretically, would be the thing you'd want to use, but the throw means it doesn't work. Very odd...

Comment: What do you mean by "the throw means it doesn't work" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'guard' like this here, in this case:

```
var mods : String = ""
guard let modpath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(filename, ofType: "ini", inDirectory: "mods/gamedata") else {
    mods = ""
}
do
{
    mods = try String(contentsOfFile: modpath!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
} 
catch ()
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, Using **Guard** i have modified your code like below. it reduces lines of code and our intension is clear too. check this code

```
var mods : String = ""

let modpath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(filename, ofType: "ini", inDirectory: "mods/gamedata")

 guard modpath?.length > 0 else { throw ErrorHandler.errorMessage }

mods = try! String(contentsOfFile: modpath!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Here you have define enum (error handler) that was extending from ErrorType protocol.